# Registros Repetidos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente codigo en el cual le indico mediante una consulta de MySQL que me imprima  cuantos comentarios se ingresaron en un folio, solo que al ingresar; por ejemplo, 3 comentarios en un mismo folio al mandarlos en la tabla para que lo muestre me muestra las 3 veces que se ingreso el comentario.

Anexo tabla donde se muestran los datos que utilizo en la consulta, esto desde la Base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De que manera se podría imprimir solo una vez dichos comentarios del folio?
Como se muestra en la imagen de la parte inferior de este post de esas 3 veces que se imprime cuantos comentarios se ingreso en el folio, solo necesito que aparezca una vez.

```
 <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" id="tablaDinamicaLoad">
         
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="1000px"><b>TIPO</b></td>
                    <td align="center" width="20px"><b>DETALLES</b></td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM notificaciones WHERE contador = '1' ORDER BY id DESC";
                $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                while ($ver = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                    $datos = $ver[0] . "||" .
                        $ver[1] . "||" .
                        $ver[2] . "||" .
                        $ver[3] . "||" .
                        $ver[4] . "||" .
                        $ver[5] . "||" .
                        $ver[6];
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" width="1000px">
                            <small>
                                <!-- COMENTARIOS -->
                                <?php

                                $sqlComent = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notificaciones WHERE tipo = 'COMENTARIO' AND contador = '1' AND folio = '$ver[1]' AND usuario = '$ver[2]'";
                                $resultComent = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlComent);
                                while ($verComent = mysqli_fetch_row($resultComent)) {

                                    $datoComent = $verComent[0];

                                    if ($ver[5] == "COMENTARIO") { ?>

                                        <b><?= $ver[2]; ?></b> agregó <b><?= $datoComent ?></b> <b><?= $ver[5]; ?></b> al folio <b><?= $ver[1]; ?></b>, con estatus <b><?= $ver[3]; ?>

                                    <?php
                                    }
                                }

                                    ?>
                            </small>
                        </td>

                        <td align="center" width="20px">
                            <form class="" action="seguimientocon.php?id=<?php echo $ver[1]; ?>" method="post">
                                <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" value="<?php echo $ver[1]; ?>" id="id" name="id"></button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**AQUÍ SE MUESTRA COMO LO COMENTADO ANTERIORMENTE SE IMPRIME**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EL RESULTADO CORRECTO DEBERÍA SER ESTE**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes! Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye más información sobre los datos que estás consultando. No es claro qué datos está consultando (podrías poner en tu pregunta datos de prueba de la tabla) y cómo debería aparecer (no conocemos la lógica de tus datos ni de tu aplicación). La opción editar está justo bajo las etiquetas

Comment: Agradezco el punto de vista, mediante el codigo estoy haciendo una consulta a la Base correspondiente para traer ciertos datos, en este caso ahorita solo estoy imprimiendo los comentarios.

Comment: De acuerdo. De nuevo, no sabemos cómo están guardados esos datos, así que es difícil opinar sobre las consultas o la lógica de tu código sin saberlo. Por eso la sugerencia de mostrar la tabla donde están los comentarios (así sea con datos falsos) y cómo deberían mostrarse finalmente

Comment: Nuevamente gracias, acabo de anexar un poco mas de información.

Comment: Vale. En la BD hay 3 notificaciones, cada una con un ID diferente, mismo folio, mismo estado y mismo usuario. Debería mostrarse sólo la más reciente? La más antigua?? Y si no son tres sino ocho, igual? Y si tienen mismo estado y diferente usuario? Todo esto que pregunto es para saber cómo agrupar los datos

Comment: Ok en este caso me iré al siguiente ejemplo, en el ID 6442, 6443, 6444 presenta que el mismo usuario Edgar_GG comento 3 veces en el folio 20920 esto hace que en la tabla arroje esos tres comentarios, por ende como tal estaría mal, porque solo necesitaría que arroje una sola notificación, y esto aunado si tengo un comentario o varios en un solo folio

Answer (score 2):

creo que puedes solucionar tu problema agregando un GROUP BY en tu primera consulta, quedaría algo así.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notificaciones WHERE contador = '1' ORDER BY id DESC GROUP BY folio";
```

Comment: Gracias por la aportación, de igual manera lo coloque así, pero al mostrar el resultado en la tabla no muestra nada.

Comment: @Nancy `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` siempre devuelve solo un registro, el problema es que cada comentario es una notificación y aparece 3 veces porque en la **consulta previa** no hay filtro o agrupamiento, tal como te sugiere en la respuesta.

Comment: @Triby al ingresar el filtro anteriormente mencionado, me muestra solo 4 resultados de un total de 10, ya no lo repite, pero no muestra todos.

Comment: @Nancy, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código y problema actual.

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenia el mismo problema, pero verifica bien tus relaciones entre tus tablas, si se imprime mas veces significa que estas relacionando mas veces el mismo dato y por eso tu resultado saldrá mas veces.

Si estas ocupando INNER JOIN verifica que tus datos alguno de tus FOREIGN KEY no se repitan mas de dos veces porque igual te arrojara mas resultados de los que esperas.

Otra opción, si quieres que solo se proyecte una vez podría ser:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notificaciones WHERE contador = '1' ORDER BY id DESC GROUP BY folio LIMIT 1";
```

Pero esto te puede generar problemas si es que debes mostrar mas del mismo folio.

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/349359)